# como buscar dados de um Api com react

Tags: javascript, react, map

estou tentando exibir propriedades de uma api com react mas recebo o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

repare que na direita a propriedade existe é eu chamo ela abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual é o layout do retorno? tem algum exemplo? por favor coloque código no lugar dessas duas imagens!

Answer (score 0):

O que acontece é que uma chamada pra API é assincrona, então quando o seu componente está renderizando pela primeira vez não recebeu ainda o resultado da API de modo que o objeto não exista, dai o erro. Você não colocou o código da chamada mas suponho que haja um setState para carros. Com isso você pode colocar {carros.show.nameBrand || ''} que dai ele não mostrará nada enquanto não receber um valor, dai quando o estado atualizar com o valor recebido pela API mostrará o nome do carro corretamente.